# How can I customize the node/add form for a content type?

Tags: nodes

How can I add some help text above the form used to create a node of a specific content type?
What is the best way to do it in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just throw a custom block in there with your instructions and set to display on /node/add/get-a-quote (Keep it simple)

Answer (score 6):

On the content type edit/creation page there is a field labeled **Explanation or submission guidelines** with a help text of:

> This text will be displayed at the top of the page when creating or
>   editing content of this type.

Simply put your instructions for the content type form in that field and save your changes.

Example:

[image: content type form]

Comment: That was my first idea too, but the help text is displayed above the page title